# conflicting return type in implementation of 'tableView:heightForFooterInSection': 'CGFloat' (aka 'double') vs 'float')

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code with error as in the subject above

-(float) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 150.0f;
}

Appreciate a fix for this ,

thanks

Comment: Did you read the error message?  It says your method should return a `double` but it returns a `float`.

Comment: What does the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForFooterInSection:  say is the return type for that method?  What is the error message saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `f` and just return `150.0`.
Because when you add a `f` at the end it creates a float and you want to return a double.
And because the method signature should be `-(CGFloat)` instead of `-(float)`

Comment: Removed the 'f' and it still gives the same error as before.

Comment: Because the return type of your function is `(float)` and it might be `(CGFloat)`

Comment: Making the change to (CGFloat) fixed the issue- thanks